# docker django: Why to copy the context into docker image, if we are overwriting it by mounting something in its place in docker compose

Tags: django, docker

I was following the tutorial for docker and django. https://devopstuto-docker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/compose/django/django.html

I see the following docker file

```
FROM python:2.7
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/   <---- WHATS THE NEED OF THIS, SINCE WE ARE MOUNTING IT IN DOCKER COMPOSE
```

Docker compose file as

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code   <----------  WHY TO MOUNT THE CODE HERE. THE IMAGE HAS THE CODE
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

I see the in docker-compose.yml that its mounting the current folder into code `- .:/code`

and in the Dockerfile also we see `ADD . /code/`

Whats the need of `ADD . /code/` if we are anyhow depend on the mounting in docker-compose which is going to overwrite the files

Comment: I'd generally avoid the volume mount.  Make the image be self-contained.  If you're going to distribute the application code anyways, a non-Docker native environment (for Python, a virtual environment) will be easier to run and have fewer dependencies.  The volume mount can also hide bugs in the Dockerfile that will only emerge during a production deployment, and that can be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's no need for `ADD . /code` if you are using this docker-compose, this is used in local development

Dockerfile with `ADD . /code` results in an image with the django app you can run anywhere, this is used in deployment